# Sendmail issue with "localhost.localdomain"

Tags: email, php, sendmail

I have a DigitalOcean server which runs Ubuntu 14.04. I am having problems with sending emails from the PHP `mail()` function (which uses `sendmail` internally).

I think the issue may be related to my `hosts` file config. Here is what I have in `/etc/hosts` at the moment:

`127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx`

And in `etc/hostname`:

`ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx`

(In the above two, I replaced the IP address digits with `x`)

Now I have a domain pointing to this server, let's call this `mydomain.com`.

So when my website `mydomain.com` sends an email, the email is going in to the junk mail folder. I ran a test on https://www.mail-tester.com and one of the issues it flags up is:

[image]

I have tried adding `mydomain.com` to the line above in the `hosts` file but this results in the email arriving after a long time or not arriving at all.

Here are the Received headers:

```
Received: from localhost.localdomain (unknown [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx])
    (using TLSv1.2 with cipher xxx (256/256 bits))
    (No client certificate requested)
    by mail-tester.com (Postfix) with ESMTPS id xxx
    for <test-xxx@mail-tester.com>; Mon, 29 Apr 2019 18:35:18 +0200 (CEST)

Received: from localhost.localdomain (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by localhost.localdomain (8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-3) with ESMTP id xxx
    for <test-xxx@mail-tester.com>; Mon, 29 Apr 2019 17:35:18 +0100

Received: from mydomain.com (www-data@localhost)
    by localhost.localdomain (8.15.2/8.15.2/Submit) with SMTP id xxx
    for <test-xxx@mail-tester.com>; Mon, 29 Apr 2019 17:35:18 +0100
```

How to fix?

Answer (score 1):

When a mail is sent via SMTP, the connecting server identifies itself via the HELO command. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#SMTP_transport_example

You need to change this in the configuration settings for the smtp client. For `sendmail` specifically, there's an example here: https://serverfault.com/questions/205271/how-to-specify-outgoing-helo-with-sendmail